# Unable to update markers on GMaps using Swift and Parse db

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, parse-platform, gmsmapview

I wrote a function that grabs the data from Parse DB and displays the markers on Google Maps. In my **ViewDidLoad** function I have **NSTimer** that calls the function every second. The problem I am experience that array of **SpotNames**, **SpotGeopoints** keeps appending and growing after each function call. Also, I am unable to remove the marker in real time on the Map if **ParkingSpotIsEmpty** value is false.

Any suggestion how to make this more efficient?

```
func displayParkingSpots() {

        let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "parkingLocations")
        // query.whereKey("ParkingSpotIsEmpty", equalTo: true)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if !(error != nil) { for object in objects! {

                if (object["ParkingSpotIsEmpty"] as! Int == 1) {
                    self.SpotNames.append(object["SpotNames"] as! String)
                    self.SpotGeoPoints.append(object["longitude"] as! PFGeoPoint)
                    self.SpotLocationLatitudes.append(self.SpotGeoPoints.last?.latitude as CLLocationDegrees!)
                    self.SpotLocationLongitudes.append(self.SpotGeoPoints.last?.longitude as CLLocationDegrees!)
                    print(self.SpotNames)
                    let parkingSpotsPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.SpotLocationLatitudes.last!, longitude: self.SpotLocationLongitudes.last!)
                    let marker = GMSMarker(position: parkingSpotsPosition)
                    marker.title = self.SpotNames.last
                    //marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImageWithColor(UIColor.greenColor())
                    marker.icon = UIImage(named: "parking-location")
                    marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = true
                    marker.map = self.gMapsView
                }

                }
            }
        }

    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        displayParkingSpots()
        gameTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(displayParkingSpots), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        gMapsView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    }
```

Comment: this is really stupid idea with the timer, you know that the parse query can be longer than just one second and you will have the same information over and over, I dont understand what you are trying to achieve with this but if you call the function in the `success block` of the parse query it will work better (but still stupid design)...if it is still appending you can use this and it will clear the array of objects `self.SpotNames.removeAll()`

Comment: Can you recommend a better design? One second was for the testing purposes, ideally it will be set to 10sec

Comment: as I said, I dont know what you want to do with it, it seems like you will be downloading all the geopoints over and over...

Comment: In my Parse DB i have a table with a lot of GeoPoints and column that stores isParkingAvailable which is Bool values. So on the map markers should appear and disappear when parking is available. That is why I call the function every 10 sec. Is the value is true marker should appear is not marker should disappear

Comment: I would rather use `fetchInBackgroundWithBlock` than just findObjects... check the documentation...https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide

Comment: How that would be better? Can you explain please. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112965/discussion-between-ray-king-and-mazel-tov).